# Engine died in Camry Altise

Tags: camry

My mum was driving her Camry and the engine just stopped.  She had to get it towed to a mechanic and they said she needs a new engine but they don't know why hers died.  Does anyone know what could have happened and could getting another engine have the same problem?

Comment: Welcome to the site. We're sorry about your Mom's car troubles, but really there isn't enough information for us to help you. What exactly happened? Was there a lot of noise or did it just quit running? Did you see any fluids running out when it died? How many miles on the Camry? V6 or 4 cylinder? Anything else you can tell us?

Comment: Generally a mechanic would place a socket on the end of the crankshaft and attempt to spin the engine by hand.  If the engine is broke, it will refuse to spin even a little bit.  Unless there is a hole in the side of the engine, it would not be easy to tell you what's wrong.  My suspicion is broken Camshaft drive belt, let valves get off timing and the valves crashed into the piston, but it could be anything. But the diagnosis is sound.  Engine no spin = replace the engine.  How many miles/KM's on the odometer on this car?

Comment: Mum was driving and there was just a little rattle and then it died - no leaks or anything.  She had it towed to her mechanic and he cant offer an explanation as to why the engine stopped, i'm assuming he tested various things to try and determine the how and why.  He thought it might be the head gasket but when he checked that out it was fine.  What do you think about replacing the engine?  She was quote $3800 by one person and $2700 by someone else, but i'm afraid if she spends the money on a new engine then the same problem might happen again.

Comment: Again, how many miles/ KM on the Camry? How much rust is on the car?  Airbags ever been deployed?  Etc...  If the body and interior is in perfect shape and mileage < 125,000 miles a rebuild is totally worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would take it somewhere else if they cant tell you why it died. Might be just sqeezing Ole Mum for money.

If the engine did die, there are test that will tell them what happened. If the timing belt did break they can visually check it, and they can perform a leak down test to determine if valves did bend.

Could also be an electrical issue.